# Как инициализировать пользовательскую mysql переменную в Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, mysql

Хочу выполнять запрос с переменной `@total`:

```
SET @total = 0;
SELECT ...
    @total := @total + x AS total_x,
    ...
WHERE
    @total < 1000
```

Через phpMyAdmin запрос работает. В Laravel проблемы. Пробовал и в одном вызове: `DB::select( DB::raw( $query))`, и в двух последовательных:

```
DB::statement( DB::raw( 'SET @total := 0'));
$results = DB::select( $query); // тут только "select.."
```

ЧЯДНТ?

Answer (score 1):

DB::select и так уже содержит сырой запрос. Уберите DB::raw и должно сработать.